# Puppeteer with old Chrome versions

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer

For some testing purposes I want to mime a web rendering service, which is actually Chrome 41 (Chrome 41.0.2272.118).

Does anybody know, whether Puppeteer would work with such an outdated version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puppeteer uses chrome-headless for doing it's stuff which was introduced on version **59**. You cannot use Puppeteer with old versions like that since the API required to run puppeteer wouldn't be there. At most you can change the UserAgent on puppeteer to have what you need.